# Function and withdrawal does not recognize the address as payable

Tags: solidity, transactions, blockchain, remix

I have this withdrawal function but an error happens:

```
TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address". --> sd.sol:138:13: | 138 | msg.sender.transfer(withdrawAmount); | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Code:

```
function withdraw(uint withdrawAmount) public returns (uint remainingBal) {
    // Check enough balance available, otherwise just return balance
    if (withdrawAmount <= balances[msg.sender]) {
        balances[msg.sender] -= withdrawAmount;
        msg.sender.transfer(withdrawAmount);
    }
    return balances[msg.sender];
}
```

I can send WEI for my contract, so it stores the WEI but I want to be able to withdraw them.

[Link do contrato](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x00169926016D7248b8D8CF065a88beCAe3d115ea#tokentxns)

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Since 0.8 `msg.sender` is not payable. To use with transfer or send it has to be converted to payable like this `payable(msg.sender).transfer(1 gwei)`.

Comment: @Ismael worked by doing what you put in, converting it to payable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the line:

```
msg.sender.transfer(withdrawAmount);
```

So I had to put msg.sender as payable.

```
payable(msg.sender).transfer(withdrawAmount);
```